# Is it mandatorty to keep the connection-alive property when we use chunked property?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-1.1, http-1.0

My client sets the following headers:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

When I retrieve responses I receive a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header but no `Connection: Keep-Alive` header. For this reason I believe I may only be receiving a partial response in my client.

### Now my question is:

Is it mandatory to set the  `Connection: Keep-Alive`  property in  `HTTP/1.1` ?

Comment: If @rdlowrey 's answer solved your question please consider accepting it. If it hasn't, please consider elaborating on why you feel it did not solve your issue. In my opinion it does solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. In the absence of a `Connection` header for messages adhering to HTTP/1.1 the default is a persistent Keep-Alive connection. If a connection header is present both parties should act accordingly given that header's value.

As stated by [RFC 2616 Section 8.1.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.2):

> A significant difference between HTTP/1.1 and earlier versions of HTTP
>   is that persistent connections are the default behavior of any HTTP
>   connection. That is, unless otherwise indicated, the client SHOULD
>   assume that the server will maintain a persistent connection, even
>   after error responses from the server.

Of course, this doesn't prevent you from explicitly setting a `Connection: close` header if you wish to close the connection once the transfer completes.